# Getting .value of Dynamic Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm pretty new to jQuery and javascript so go easy on me. I have a select box with the id="select-cat". This select box is being created dynamically so I went ahead and used the .on event handler like so:

```
$(document.body).on('change', '#select-cat', function() {

});
```

My problem arises when I try to get the option value. Here are a few things that I've tried:

```
var x = this.value; //doesnt work, I'm assuming in this case "this" refers to document.body
```

---

```
$('#select-cat').on('change', function() { //"this" works, but event isn't added to dynamically created elements
    var x = this.value;
});
```

Does anyone have a method I could use to keep this event handler on dynamic elements while still being able to pull their values?

Comment: It works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/tZhRW/

Comment: You should be using `$(this).val()`

Comment: @zzzzBov Why **should** they?

Comment: @Ian, because `$(this).val()` will normalize accessing the value cross browser, and `<select>` elements have quite a number of niche issues that it's worthwhile to simply use `$(this).val()` instead of `this.value`, however I left that as a comment, because i hadn't intended on writing a full answer.

Comment: In my opinion, they should'nt, `this.value` is much cleaner, and avoids calling jQuery, and it should work in all newer browsers.

Comment: You may need to change `document.body` to `document`.

Comment: @zzzzBov I agree - if you look at the jQuery source, there's an entry for "select" in the `valHooks`, which does a lot for certain cases. It just would've been more helpful to explain something like that, because it's helpful specifically for `<select>` (and a few others, but not `<input />`)

Comment: @Ian, while that's true for `<input>` elements currently, I'd still recommend using `val()` for input elements simply because jQuery will probably be able to fix any future incompatibilities with `<input>` elements, especially as we start introducing more involved elements like `input[type="color"]`. Certainly if you need to worry about performance, `input.value` will be much faster, but the vast majority of the time you don't need to worry about performance in JS because JS spends most of its time waiting for events to be fired.

Comment: @zzzzBov But at the same time, the `valHooks` is specifically for special scenarios like a `<select multiple="multiple">`, or being disabled. Otherwise it doesn't seem to do much extra for getting the `.value` of a normal `<select>`

Comment: @zzzzBov I **always** use jQuery methods when I can, but these are the things that should be brought up in the first place instead of just saying "you should use". To be consistent in your programming, you should continually use the same method (like always using `.val()`), especially when it's reliable. But in this specific case, just getting a `<select>`'s value, it's not necessary. It's recommended, but works fine without it

Comment: @Ian - A select will get the same value as the selected option, and that's even in the W3C specs somewhere, and it works in all browsers, so that's not the issue here !

Comment: Well it looks like `$(document.body).on('change', '#select-cat', function() { var x = this.value; });` is working. I have absolutely no idea why it wasn't before. Maybe the .js file was saved in cache. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @crayon. - thats up to you, in my opinion it's of no use to future visitors, and could just as well be deleted !

Comment: @adeneo I know, and it's exactly what jQuery's `.val()` does - I was never arguing against it...I was arguing for it. But jQuery does normalize what's returned when dealing with `<select multiple="multiple">`

Comment: @crayon. Flag this question and explain why you want it deleted. It's not going to help anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Check out .on using: [jQuery Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('change', '#select-cat', function() {
    var x = this.value;
});
```

Comment: @Ian OP is binding to body

Comment: the only reason this would work over `document` would be if the script was being executed in the `<head>` where `document.body` doesn't yet exist. `$(document.body)` would be a slightly better delegate parent as there would be one less traversal before the callbacks are fired.

Comment: @Zenith I was suggesting him to give an accurate read on its working, because using $(document).on(event, selector, handler) is the best way, imo, to avoid any type of problem with dynamically generated elements.

Comment: If you attach all your event listeners to document, it would eventually be slow because of the sheer amount of events it has to handle. It is better to attach to a known parent element in the DOM for better performance and logically grouping the events to the elements it's interacting with.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('body').on('change', '#select-cat', function() {
   var value = $(this).find('option:selected').val();

   // do something with the value..
});
```

The select box itself doesn't have a val, the 'selected' option has a value